# else part of if statement always been run when if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

Tags: php, mysql, forms, if-statement, authentication

I have created a login form cannot get it to work.

My select statement is correct (works on the database) and the echo from $query resolves the following (for example)

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'test@test.com' AND password = password
```

However in the if statement underneath it always process' the following code

```
else
 {
 echo "Your login is invalid";
 echo $_POST['username'];
}
```

The full code is below

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . ('/../config/init.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php 
    include INCLUDES . 'head_tags.php';
?>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
    <?php
        include INCLUDES . 'header.php';
        include INCLUDES . 'nav.php';
    ?>
    <div class='two-thirds column'>
        <h2>Login</h2>
            <form action='#' method='post'>

            <div>
                <label for="username">Username (E-email address):</label>
                <input type='text' id="username" name='username' placeholder='Username' autocomplete='on' required>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type='password' id='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' autocomplete='on' required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <?php
                    if($_POST){

                        $connection = mysql_connect($db['hostname'], $db['username'], $db['password']) or die(mysql_error());
                        mysql_select_db($db['database'], $connection) or die(mysql_error());

                        /*Echo's to check correct data is being used
                        echo $_POST['username'];
                        echo $_POST['password'];*/

                        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = ".$_POST['password']."";


                        echo $query;

                        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$query");

                        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
                            echo "You have successfully logged on";
                            }
                        else
                            {
                            echo "Your login is invalid";
                            echo $_POST['username'];
                            }

                    }

                ?>  
            </div>
            <input type='submit' value='submit'>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    include INCLUDES . 'footer.php';
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead deprecated `mysql_*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missign quotes at password.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" . $email . "' AND password = '" . $_POST['password'] . "'";
```

`Real_escape_string()` has to be used to password too and, of course, you have to hash passwords, now your query is not protected from SQL injection.

Comment: If you are voting down, write a reason here. What exactly is for minus in this answer?